# Call to a member function query() on null error when using function in child class

Tags: php, class, oop

I have two classes, one connection class and one class which contains code for a menu.

First I am trying to get all the categories from my menu (from the database), so I try to use the `query` function from my connection class. But this gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function query() on null in <b>mywebsitepath/includes/menuClass.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

I'm new to OOP but I thought when extending the connection class, I can just use the functions in the child class.

This is my connection class:

```
<?PHP
session_start();

class Connection {
    // Configure Database Vars
    private $host     = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'user';
    private $password = 'pass!';
    private $db_name  = 'dbname';
    public $db;

    function __construct() {
        // Create connection
        $db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
        // Check connection
        if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
            die('Unable to connect to the database: '.$db->connect_error);
        }
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $db = $this->db;
        $this->db->query('SET NAMES utf8');
        if (!$result = $this->db->query($query)) {
            die('There was an error running the query ['.$db->error.']');
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function multi_query($query) {
        $db = $this->db;
        if (!$result = $this->db->multi_query($query)) {
            die('There was an error running the multi query ['.$db->error.']');
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function real_escape_string($value) {
        return $this->db->real_escape_string($value);
    }

    public function inserted_id() {
        return $this->db->insert_id;
    }
}

$conn = new Connection;
?>
```

And this is my small beginning attempt at a menu class:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/connection.php');
class Menu extends Connection
{
  public function selectCats()
  {
    $cats = "SELECT * FROM snm_categories WHERE published = '1'";
    $catscon = $conn->query($cats);
    return $cats;
  }
}
 ?>
```

On my index I want to loop the results:

```
$menu = new Menu();
$cats = $menu->selectCats();
```

(No loop yet but first I want to get rid of the error)

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend that you change the class structure.  A Menu isn't really a 'type of' connection.  It uses a connection.

Comment: So instead of extending it, what do I do. Instantiate the connection class above my menu class?

Comment: You see a common pattern where the connection is passed into the constructor of any class which needs to use it (quick search - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308886/recommended-way-for-passing-data-connection-to-a-php-class-method).  Also linked with dependency injection and helps with testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your derived class, your using `$conn`, which isn't defined anywhere, you need to use the connection defined in your base class...

```
$catscon = $this->db->query($cats);
```

Answer (score 2):

You called the variable in the connection object property `$db`

But in the `selectCats` method you are using `$con` which does not exist. You also forgot to use `$this->` in front of the variable which is required to tell PHP to look in this object and/or its parents for the property.

So amend code to

```
<?php
require_once('includes/connection.php');
class Menu extends Connection
{
    public function selectCats()
    {
    $cats = "SELECT * FROM snm_categories WHERE published = '1'";
    $catscon = $this->db->query($cats);
    //         ^^^^^^^^^  changed here
    return $cats;
    }
}
?>
```